# CSS not being applied to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have a rather simple page currently, and for some reason the maincss.css isn't being applied, which simply sets the background to an image. I know that it works because it was working before I added another css file for jquery styling. What about this is wrong?

```
<html xmlns=\ "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">
<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" CONTENT="text/javascript">
  <title>Welcome to Jetty-9</title>
  <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      width: 400,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Ok",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nothing is wrong with the above code, please use chrome or firefox and see if you have any errors or warnings when you inspect element or hit F12.  Thanks

Comment: I don't believe any of the paths are incorrect, as when I view page source and click each of the .js and .css files they open correctly

Comment: Is the path to the image correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you might face problem because:

1. In CSS file the image path you have not given properly. (you should be giving a relative path from your CSS file and not to html)
2. In your new CSS file the `body{}` tag was overwritten to nothing.

For resolution:
Try checking the CSS by configuring the `background-color` to some color and test it. So this way you can make sure the CSS is working fine and try other options as well.

Comment: Ended up being that I moved the css file from the root to a css folder, and didnt change the relative image path. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" CONTENT="text/javascript">
  <title>Welcome to Jetty-9</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" href="css/maincss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog({
      width: 400,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Ok",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you care to explain what you changed, and why it might help?

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Just added <!DOCTYPE html> and transformed to HTML5